# Owl carousel animation not applied in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, owl-carousel

I am working on an HTML5 theme which uses the [Owl Carouse 1.3.2](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html). I want to apply the fade animation while transition of the slider image. Below is my code and it is working fine in **Mozilla Browser**, but the **Chrome browser** still shows the simple left-right animation.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    "use strict";
    jQuery("#layout").owlCarousel({
        pagination: false,
        autoPlay: 4000,
        slideSpeed: 600,
        transitionStyle: "fade",
        navigation: false,
        singleItem: true
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="layout" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="sliders/slider_1.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="sliders/slider_2.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="sliders/slider_3.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="sliders/slider_4.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="sliders/slider_5.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try to clean the cache of your browser. If it not helps, try to provide a Fiddle

Comment: Define "It's not working". Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. "It's not working"-means the chrome shows left-right animation, even after defining fade in animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [line 806](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/blob/4460c16a26b1bba1309b672c8c7c53cb519aca98/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js#L806) of **owl.carousel.js** change:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

To:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length > 0);
```

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/480) for this on GitHub.